# Можно ли как-то константный метод в наследуемом классе сделать неконстантным? C++

Tags: c++, ооп

Допустим есть абстрактный класс:

```
class MyClass {

public:

    virtual foo() const = 0;

}
```

Можно ли в наследуемом классе как-то сделать foo() неконстантным? Переопределение без const не работает.

Comment: думаю, Вам нужно просто нужные переменные в наследнике пометить как mutable и все будет ок. Либо рассказать свою задачу глубже.

Comment: @KoVadim нет, не поможет. В моем случае я использую графическую библиотеку, в которой метод, ответственный за отрисовку виджетов помечен как const (как по мне плохое решение). В этом методе перед отрисовкой виджетов мне нужно сдвигать виджет на определенное количество пикселей (реализация отступа). Конечно, можно сделать по-другому, но в данном случае это самый правильный вариант. Ну и const в методе не дает мне этого сделать., поскольку метод .move не является const

Comment: @KoVadim однако за mutable спасибо, не знал про это, на первый взгляд кажется полезным.

Comment: вот тут я бы подумал, возможно, функция отрисовки далеко не самое лучшее место, что бы менять объекты. Обычно для такого заводят функцию Update и в ней объекты могут пересчитать свои позиции-размеры.

Comment: @KoVadim все именно так, но возможности это библиотеки таковы, что даже сама функция update должна будет находиться в функции для отрисовки. Грубо говоря, внешний объект (окно) для отрисовки вызывает функцию draw() у виджета. А в draw() виджета нужно прописать window.draw(this) (передать указатель в окно). Ну вот так библиотека сделана. Не знаю зачем, но мне кажется, что это реализация кривая. Приходится подстраиваться) Библиотека SFML

Comment: Функция update однозначно не должна находится в функции для отрисовки, а то у вас выйдет, что скорость изменений будет привязана к частоте отрисовки, а-ля Commodore . Люди с монитором 240 Гц явно не обрадуются.

Comment: функцию update в случае 99% библиотек можно и нужно вызывать с цикла обработки сообщений. И а потом отрисовку.

Comment: @KoVadim то есть из отдельного объекта вызываем update, а из update - draw? Я даже и не подумал, честно говоря. Столько проблем решит. Тупанул, спасибо огромное

Comment: Я не говорил, что с update надо вызывать draw, обычно так никто не делает. Update вызывается по таймеру, а update в цикле. Скорее всего Ваше решение потом взорвет все, но...

Comment: @KoVadim ну я это и имел ввиду. Update вызывается в цикле, а из него draw, поскольку в SFML, как я понимаю, встроенный таймер и draw() так или иначе тоже вызывается в цикле

Comment: На сайте SFML есть линки на книги по SFML. :)

Comment: @ComeInRage, если ты уверен, что дело в кривом API библиотеки, а не в том, что ты не умеешь её использовать, то можно сделать `const_cast` `this`'а... но это относительно грязный хак и вся ответственность за последствия исключительно на тебе...

Comment: @Fat-Zer да, знаю про эту штуку, но я действительно ошибся и неправильно использовал библиотеку. К тому же я приверженец того, что подобные касты сигнализируют о том, что ты что-то в своей жизни делаешь не так. Поэтому и написал сюда и мне помогли решить проблему, указав где я ошибся :)